# Battery Monitoring System for Arduino

Tags: battery

I need to incorporate a battery monitor using a 10 led bar graph. I am powering the arduino with a 7.4(though it reads 7.67) V  lithium polymer battery through the arduino`s power jack. The goal is to monitor that battery. How would I go about doing this? I have a LM3914 driver to use if I want but I am clueless as to what to do.

Comment: Create a voltage dividerm using two resistors, to safely measure the battery voltage. Just note that the voltage drops faster when the battery is getting low (i.e. the relation with battery voltage and remaining capacity isn't linear). Though who cares if the battery is 90% or 80%, we care more about the 20% versus 10%.

Comment: Google is your friend - https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/dotbar-display-driver-hookup-guide